# Python counting issue

Tags: python, matplotlib, counting, cellular-automata

I've got some nested functions and I'm trying to sum the total number of times that something occurs using:

```
if C[city_cell_x][city_cell_y] == 1:
  cityCount +=1
```

but as this is within a function:

```
    # Animate

fig = plt.figure()
plt.axis("on")
ims = []
for t in range(totalTime):
    print(str(r), " Time = " + str(t))
    ims.append((plt.imshow(C, cmap="Accent"),))
    C = mapRun(C)
if C[city_cell_x][city_cell_y] == 1:
  cityCount +=1
im_ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(
    fig, ims, interval=interval, repeat_delay=3000, blit=True
)

# Save the animation?
if save:
  print("Saving...")
  im_ani.save(("Repeat" + str(r) + ".html"), writer="html", fps=60, dpi=75)
```

which I am then looping over, it is either not successfully counting and just returning zero at the end, of it is raising "cityCount referenced before assignment" even though it is referenced at the start of the code (outside of the function)

I can provide the entire code if that is easier

Comment: Sounds like a scope issue - maybe if you had `cityCount` as an instance variable on an object, you could keep track of it better?

Comment: This is currently unanswerable. You say the code is inside a function, but you don't define any function in the question, so it's not possible to know what name is in what scope. Please give an [mcve]

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are trying to do, but shouldn't the two lines where you do the counting be part of the `for` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem may be a what is described [here](https://github.com/satwikkansal/wtfpython#-the-out-of-scope-variable).

If you created `cityCount` outside your function and are now trying to assign to it inside, what you are getting is a new local variable.

If the `if` statement is never true, `cityCount` is never incremented but the code runs fine.
If the `if` statement is true, you get the error because there is no local `cityCount` to add to.

The solution would be to add `global cityCount` to the beginning of the function.